# Django: How do I remove the ending "?" from the URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I need to remove the "?" at the end of my URL:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path("map_fslis_top/totals/<int:fstype_id>", views.edit_totals, name="edit_totals"),]
```

view.py

```
def edit_totals(request, fstype_id):
    # Some code...
    return render(request, "DataMech/totals.html", {
        'fstype': fstype,
        'typefslis': typefslis,
        'totals': totals,
    })
```

html trigger

```
<button href="{% url 'edit_totals' fstype_id=fstype.id %}" class="btn btn-primary" class="form-control" type="submit" value="submit">Totals</button>
```

The URL of the page generated: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/map_fslis_top/totals/1?`

How do I get rid of that ugly "?" at the end of the URL?

Comment: You can add a dollar sign to the end of your url pattern - `<int:fstype_id>$`

Answer (score 0):

Adding / does seem to work but it just replaces the ? sign. Not eliminate it.

I found a solution though. Just wrapped the button in an 'a' tag and it seems to work. No ? or any other symbol at the end of the URL.

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_totals' fstype_id=fstype.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary" class="form-control">Totals</button></a>
```